# SimpleDateFormat string parsing issue in a Specific Android Device

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, xiaomi

I have a released android app and a strange issue has cropped up with a specific device. On analysis of Crashlytics data, I found that the app is crashing for this particular user (and device) because of the following reason:

```
val time1 = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault()).parse(dateString)
```

where dateString is "Sep 6 2023 14:00:00"

The exact error reported issue is

Caused by java.text.ParseException
Unparseable date: "Sep 6 2023 14:00:00"

I have not faced this issue before in other devices. The specifics of the device are:

Device
Brand:Xiaomi
Model:Redmi Note 10 Pro
Orientation:Portrait
RAM free: 1.88 GB
Disk free: 2.48 GB
Operating System
Version:Android 13
Orientation:Portrait
Rooted:No
Crash
Date:Sep 5, 2023, 4:19:40 PM
App version:6.1.2 (54)

Additional input:

It also fails with

deteString: "Sep 15 2023 24:00:00"

So the problem is not with d or dd

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: What is the default locale of that device where it does not work? I bet it has a language setting where the abbreviation for *September* is not `Sep`. If `Sep` is supposed to be English, specify an English-speaking locale. `LocalDateTime.parse("Sep 15 2023 24:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.ROOT))` returns `2023-09-16T00:00`. 24 o’clock is taken as midnight and renedered as 00:00:00 the next day (the old-fashioned classes did something similar).

Comment: As @OleV.V. has rightly guided you, the problem is because of `Locale.getDefault()`. Using `Locale.getDefault()` is anyway useless with a date-time-formatter. For an English text like  *Sep 6 2023 14:00:00*, you must use `Locale.ENGLISH` or `Locale.ROOT`.

Comment: Yet a similar question: [new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).parse("04:30 PM") giving Unparseable exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53313558/new-simpledateformathhmm-a-locale-getdefault-parse0430-pm-giving-un)

Comment: @OleV.V. I am taking your suggestion and would discard the SimpleDateFormat in the next major update of the app. Date is cornerstone of my app and is used at multiple places. So I would need sometime to make the update. In the meantime using Arvind's suggestion for a quick fix.

Comment: @oTwo You can easily convert to and from `java.util.Date` and `java.time.Instant` via new methods added to the old class. Do all your work in *java.time*, then convert where you need to interoperate with old code.

Comment: @oTwo Your string input lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC.  But `java.util.Date` (and `Instant`) represent a date and time as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds. Do you know the time zone or offset intended for your input string?

Comment: `java.util.Date.from( java.time.LocalDateTime.parse( "Sep 6 2023 14:00:00" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM d uuuu HH:mm:ss" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ).atZone( "Asia/Tokyo" ).toInstant() )`

Comment: I have resolved the issue temporarily by using Locale.ENGLISH. What intrigues me is the fact that this case was reported by only one user. Works fine for others

Answer (score -1):

Your date is of single character e.g. '6' in "Sep 6 2023 14:00:00"

Try format "MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss" as follow:

```
val pattern = SimpleDateFormat("MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault())
val time1 = pattern.parse(dateString)
```

or update your date generation to '06' for single characters

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. Challenge is that it would take me some time to realise if this worked. Any idea why this is not happening for other devices?

Comment: The issue persists with "Sep 15 2023 24:00:00". So the problem is not d or dd. Same device

Comment: On my computer too I still get `ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sep 6 2023 14:00:00"`. Sorry to say, I’m afraid your answer doesn’t help. Which I find OK since helping users how to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDatFormat` is really doing them an ill favour. Everyone is much better off switching to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: I'm afraid, it couldn't work for you. Do it throws the exception for any dates for all times? or for specific strings?

Comment: Using your code I get `ParseException` for all of `Sep 6 2023 14:00:00` , `Sep 06 2023 14:00:00` and `Sep 26 2023 14:00:00`. See [the linked original question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025528/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-java-text-dateformat-parsedateforma) for the correct solution.